# I couldn't see the java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: android

Can Anyone help me please? explain to me why this code is "java.lang.NullPointerException" error.

```
final ImageButton sampleImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sample);

    final Dialog dd_dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dd_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.Sample_layout);
    dd_dialog.setTitle("Sample");
    dd_dialog.setCancelable(true);

sampleImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dd_dialog.show();
                }
            });
```

here's the xml

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_sample"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:background="#4372AA"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
```

Comment: Also sampleImageButton isn't same as prescribeImageButton

Comment: i already edit the code.. but the error is pointing to this code

    sampleImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: hmmm,getting `NPE` because probably ImageView is inside layout of Dialog. so try it as :`final ImageButton sampleImageButton = (ImageButton) dd_dialog .findViewById(R.id.btn_sample);
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K actually the error is pointing to this part

    sampleImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: @anupDasari here's the logcat errors

FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: sample.sample.com.sampledesign, PID: 32593
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: at sample.sample.com.sampledesign.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:116)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)

Comment: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя it didn't work either sorry

Comment: @Kiel: Show your updated code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя here's the new structure of the codes:

    final Dialog dd_dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    final ImageButton sampleImageButton = (ImageButton) dd_dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_sample);

    dd_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.Sample_layout);
    dd_dialog.setTitle("Sample");
    dd_dialog.setCancelable(true);

then the onclicklistener here

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I found the problem just now, thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is here you have taken button in xml layout and in java file you declare ImageButton so change from ImageButton to Button.

change this line from

```
final ImageButton sampleImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sample);
```

To

```
final Button sampleImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sample);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you haven't set the activity view using `setContentView` before using `findViewById`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

probably this must be the correction :

```
final ImageButton sampleImageButton = (ImageButton) dd_dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_sample);
```

add this below of

```
final Dialog dd_dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dd_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.Sample_layout);
```